# How to detect a GDAL/OGR 'Warning'?

Tags: python, gdal, .net, ogr

- When I run a *batch script* using a *GDAL/OGR* program, I can detect if an error occured by checking `ERRORLEVEL` for the value 1.
- When using GDAL/OGR in *python* or *.NET*, I get an exception when an error occurs.

**Question:**
How do I detect if a `Warning` was issued during the execution?

---

***Why?***
*Even though a process can execute to the end despite of warnings, the output might be corrupt with respect to the data I expect. You could argue that I ought to check for these corruptions, but since I have control of the entire process, I would like to be able to stop when a warning is issued.*

Comment: You can modify the error handling behaviour at the C level (see http://www.gdal.org/cpl__error_8h.html), including turning warning into errors and setting error handlers. I don't see anything that will expose that to non-C APIs though.

Comment: I think this question is more fitted to be asked at http://www.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: **@BradHards**: I would rather not dive into the C code and compile the stuff my self.

Comment: **@nickves**: I have asked the question here because I expect the folks using GDAL/OGR to be using this forum.

Answer (score 5):

If using GDAL 1.10+ the python bindings allow you to specify a python callable as an error handler.  However, any exceptions raised in these error handlers do not propagate back to the main thread. So something like this won't work:

```
from osgeo import gdal


def error_handler(err_level, err_no, err_msg):
    if err_level == gdal.CE_Warning:
        raise RuntimeError(err_msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    gdal.SetErrorHandler(error_handler)
    gdal.UseExceptions()

    try:
        gdal.Error(gdal.CE_Warning, 2, "warning message")
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print(f"Warning was raised: {err}")
```

You'll actually see a `SystemError: <built-in function Error> returned a result with an exception set`

But you can do something like:

```
from osgeo import gdal

class GdalErrorHandler(object):
    def __call__(self, err_level, err_no, err_msg):
        self.err_level = err_level
        self.err_no = err_no
        self.err_msg = err_msg


if __name__ == "__main__":

    handler = GdalErrorHandler()
    gdal.PushErrorHandler(handler)
    gdal.UseExceptions()  # Exceptions will get raised on anything >= gdal.CE_Failure

    try:
        gdal.Error(gdal.CE_Warning, 1, "from gdal.CE_Warning!!!")
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print(f"handling any  actual errors {err}")
    else:  # Handle any warnings
        if handler.err_level >= gdal.CE_Warning:
            print(f"handling any warnings {handler.err_msg}")
```

Comment: Will this capture errors from functions like `Gdal.Warp()`?

Comment: The question and answer is about catching *warnings*.  Just tell gdal to raise exceptions for *errors* with `gdal.UseExceptions()`.